# How do I get someone's location every few seconds?

Tags: android, location

I am trying to make a simple app that revolves around tracking someone's speed. I have read through Android Studio's Location guide, however it doesn't show how to get someone's speed, or get someone's location at an even interval.

Currently, I have this snippet of code set up:

```
if (OldLocation != null) {
            OldLocation = NewLocation;
            NewLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
        } else {
            OldLocation = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
            try {Thread.sleep(1000);} catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }
            NewLocation = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        }
        float distance = OldLocation.distanceTo(NewLocation);
        float speed = distance / 1000;
```

I am currently using Thread.sleep to do this, though I think there would be a better way to request updates periodically.

Can anyone show me how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is the worst way you can possible do it.  For a dozen reasons you should almost never use getLastKnownLocation-  and getting continual updates is definitely NOT one of those places to do it.  Instead, use LocationManager.requestLocationUpdates().  You provide it a callback object and it calls you when an updated position is available.

Also, use LocationManager or the Google Play Fused Location.  There's no good reason to mix and match.

Comment: Is there any way to request a location every say, 5 seconds?

Comment: That's a bit too fast. Request location updates will call you every n seconds, but only if it has an update. GPS generally updates you location about twice a minute

Comment: Okay. I guess I wouldn't need to set a specific interval then. Thank you for your help!